# Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}' - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have checked and the property does exist with the key but it returns the error `name is not a property of {}`. I tried to assign this object to an interface complete with its properties however it also says I cannot assign {} to it. What could be the problem to this?

This is the code that doesn't work
`this.companiesArray[0].employees[0].name` which returns the error `name is not a property of {}`.

This is the sample data I'm working with, an array of objects (Companies)

```js
[
{
"employees": [
  {
    "name": "Amy",
    "gender": "female",
    "level": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Chris",
    "gender": "male",
    "level": "4"
  }
  ],
"company": "XYZ",
"tower": "Tower 2"
 },
 {
"employees": [
  {
    "name": "Ben",
    "gender": "male",
    "level": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Sarah",
    "gender": "female",
    "level": "1"
  }
  ],
"company": "ABC",
"tower": "Tower 3"
 }
 ]
```

Here is the Angular code and the Company Interface

```js
 companiesArray: Company[]
  ngOnInit() {
    this.companyService.obsCompanies.subscribe(companies => {
      this.companiesArray = companies;
      console.log(this.companiesArray[0].employees[0].name);// for testing
    });
 ...
  }
```

```js
export interface Company {
    employees: {}[],
    company: string,
    tower: string
}
```

Comment: Please provide your angular code as well. Your `model`, `interface`, `component` etc, anything that relates to your question.

Comment: btw, I already tested this code `this.companiesArray[0].employees[0].name` along with your sample data. Everything just fine. I got the name 'Amy' as expected.

Comment: Information is not suffice to conclude what is going wrong.

Comment: For now, I guess the error come for the `this` variable. Then, you should provide your angular code, where you trying to pull out the value of `name`.

Comment: angular code please

Comment: @penleychan I have attached it already

Comment: @Arash edited post :)

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú i have added it :)

Comment: @SagarKharche updated the post :)

Comment: Wrong types `employees: {}[]`

Comment: does `companies` in the line `this.companiesArray = companies;` has value. Did you test it first before pulling the value of `name`?

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú yes i tested it and it has content

Answer (score 3):

Create an interface Employee

```
export interface Employee {
    name: string;
    gender: string;
    level: string;
}
```

and change Company to

```
export interface Company {
    employees: Employee[],
    company: string,
    tower: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a compiler error you get when you call a function with a generic signature and if you do not specify a type to the function call and the compiler cannot infer the type so it infers type {}.

You need to define the type on the function call so that the compiler knows the type. Something like yourService.get<YourType>( rather than yourService.get(

Comment: Please, merge your answers and remove one